# Case statement for MSB

Tags: verilog

I have a question regarding the MSB for input data.

I have an 8-bit register for my input. In my case statement, I only care about the value of my MSB but I am unsure of how to determine this in an efficient manner. For example, I do not want to do the following:

```
code...

case(INP)
2'b10000000://stuff
2'b10000001://stuff
2'b10000010://stuff 

...
```

There must be a better way to do this. Would this work (see below)?

```
code...

    case(INP)
    2'b1XXXXXXX://stuff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `casez` is for. A `?` in a literal gets converted to a Z, and `casez` treats that as a don't care.

```
case(INP)
  8'b1???????://stuff
  8'b00000001://morestuff
  8'b0?00001?:// matches 00000010 000000011 01000010 010000011
endcase
```